# Axes keeps chaning size with imshow

Tags: image, matlab, axes

I'm using imshow to plot a logical array that represents the letter "A". I also have an edit box that the user can enter to values in to describe the number of slices in the x and y direction; i.e. 10,10. The default is 10,10 when the GUI starts. If I change either of the numbers, the new logical array is shown with imshow but now it is larger than the axes that I have already placed in the GUI. I've included some screen grabs to show what is happening. Also, I noticed that the Pixel Map image is larger than the size of the axes that I originally had (which is the same size as the axes for the sample image). Is there a way to fix these issues? I can't figure this out.

[image: default]

[image: 10x20]

Comment: I am not sure I understood what the problem is, but did you try interpolation='none'? Also, pcolormesh() may answer your needs.

Comment: I basically want the image size to remain the same regardless of the grid size. The pixel representation of the letter "A" does not show entirely in the axes, it looks like it was scaled up. I tried your suggestions but they did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem is that the pixel map is being constrained to an axes in which the x limits and y limits are not wide enough, probably:

```
xlim = [1,10]
ylim = [1 10]
```

To fix this, try the following:

```
set(axH, 'XLim', [1 xGrid])
set(axH, 'YLim', [1 yGrid])
```

where `axH` is the handle to the pixel map in the figure on the right, and `xGrid` and `yGrid` are your pixel map dimensions (e.g., 10 & 20 in your second example).

If you don't have access to the axes handle for some reason, you can try modifying it directly by using

```
xlim([1 xGrid])
ylim([1 yGrid])
```

immediately after you plot the pixel map.

Comment: This kind of worked. If I change the grid size to say 5,5 the pixel map does not show entirely. This is the top of the letter "A". http://i38.tinypic.com/6jpkz5.jpg